# Changing the z-index of data points and/or series in ScatterChart javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8, scatter-plot

I have had issues trying to change the order in which data series are layed out in a ScatterChart.
Basically, regarding multiple series, the layout order is given from the order the series are added to the chart. Yet, if I remove one and add it again later, it will appear on top.
I tried :

```
 myChart.getData().add(specificIndex, series)
```

to make sure that the last one is not on top, but it doesn't work

I also tried:

```
 myChart.getData().add(lastSeries);
 myChart.getData().stream().sort((seriesA, seriesB)->myComparator(seriesA, seriesB));
```

But it does not work either.

Also, I experience similar problems when it comes to displaying data points.
Basically, I am trying to create a scattered heatmap where points are colored depending on their density on the chart. So the data is associated with a Rectangle Node that is colored with a hue proportional to the number of nodes present within a given radius.

This is fine, except that in very dense region, some points are hiding others with higher density, and the end result is not representative of the density function...

The only work around was this (for series):

```
 myChart.getData().clear()
 myChart.getData().addAll(myCorrectlyOrderedListOfSeries);
```

which seems very dirty and computationnaly inneficient...

any other way?

**EDIT**

I actually solved the problem for data Point, realizing that there was a "toFront" method.

Yet, since I don't have a node for the series, I don't know on which Item I should call the **toFront()** regarding the series. Do I really need to call in on all data points from all series, in the order I want for the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Node tree generated by a scatter chart, and in fact, all the dataPoints are actually children of the same group, regardless of the Series they belong too.

So there is no other way than the following to put the series in the correct order:

```
//List<Series<Double, Double>> myOrderedListOfSeries;

myOrderedListOfSeries.forEach(series->
    series.getData().forEach(dataPoint->
         dataPoint.getNode().toFront()
     )
 );
```